# Video cover Facebook API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to take the cover of a Facebook page . I can take it with `field=cover`, and it gives me a picture. But when it's a video (you can see one on this page facebook.com/renaultfrance), it gives me a preview of the video, and a picture too. I'd need the whole video, i tried to use `lenght` on the id I have with `field=cover`, but the API returned an error. I think it's because I try a video field on a photo. Has someone here tried this ? Could you help me ? Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the code you're using

Comment: Im not using any code yet, just HTTPS requests